# Trouble finding shortest path across a 2D mesh surface

Tags: algorithm, matlab, dijkstra

I asked this question three days ago and I got burned by contributors because I didn't include enough information. I am sorry about that.

I have a 2D matrix and each array position relates to the depth of water in a channel, I was hoping to apply Dijkstra's or a similar "least cost path" algorithm to find out the least amount of concrete needed to build a bridge across the water.

It took some time to format the data into a clean version so I've learned some rudimentary Matlab skills doing that. I have removed most of the land so that now the shoreline is standardised to a certain value, my plan is to use a loop to move through each "pixel" on the "west" shore and run a least cost algorithm against it to the closest "east" shore and move through the entire mesh ultimately finding the least cost one.

This is my problem, fitting the data to any of the algorithms. Unfortunately I get overwhelmed by options and different formats because the other examples are for other use cases.

My other consideration is that when the shortest cost path is calculated that it will be a jagged line which would not be suitable for a bridge so I need to constrain the bend radius in the path if at all possible and I don't know how to go about doing that.

A picture of the channel:

[image]

Any advice in an approach method would be great, I just need to know if someone knows a method that should work, then I will spend the time learning how to fit the data.

Comment: You've asked it before? In that case, the proper action would be to edit your question to include the information.

Comment: So you want the shortest path in a mesh. But that kind of contradicts the body of the question: You don't need to shortest path, and you don't need it in a mesh, you are just discretizing your data over a mesh. The big problem here is coming up with a "cost" fucntion, a fucntion that given a path, will give you the amount of concrete. We can not find that for you, as it is not a programming question, but a research question. Remember that Stackoverflow is for programming question, not about problems you want to solve *using* proggramming

Comment: SomePerson, I will update the old question.
Ander I can do the research on the amount of concrete, obviously I was not looking for help on that, I was looking on how to generate the least cost path from one shore to another. It seems like a very basic example, I am surprised this situation has never been brought up in all the examples across the docs and forums.

Comment: aha!  Becuase either you are giving too much information and not being clear about what you want or it is a really hard example. Machine learnign algorithms are created to solve this, mathematicians study convergence of algorithms in convex and non-convex scenarios. It is not a simple example. Unless you want the shortest path between 2 poitns and thats a stragth line.

Comment: @anderbiguri you answer is not helpful in this context and only adds to my frustration in trying to get into this area.

Comment: @drcross welcome to engineering, where problems are frustrating and you need to research them yourself!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Dijkstra to your problem in this way:

1. the two "dry" regions you want to connect correspond to matrix entries with value 0; the other cells have a positive value designating the depth (or the cost of filling this place with concrete)
2. your edges are the connections of neighbouring cells in your matrix. (It can be a 4- or 8-neighbourhood.) The weight of the edge is the arithmetic mean of the values of the connected cells.
3. then you apply the Dijkstra algorithm with a starting point in one "dry" region and an end point in the other "dry" region.

The cheapest path will connect two cells of value 0 and its weight will correspond to sum of costs of cells visited. (One half of each cell weight is coming from the edge going to the cell, the other half from the edge leaving the cell.)

This way you will get a possibly rather crooked path leading over the water, which may be a helpful hint for where to build a cheap bridge.

You can speed up the calculation by using the A*-algorithm. Therefore one needs a lower bound of the remaining costs for reaching the other side for each cell. Such a lower bound can be calculated by examining the "concentric rings" around a point as long as rings do not contain a 0-cell of the other side. The sum of the minimal cell values for each ring is then a lower bound of the remaining costs.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, which emphasizes the constraint that you require a non-jagged shape for your bridge, would be to use Monte-Carlo, simulated annealing or a genetic algorithm, where the initial "bridge" consisted a simple spline curve between two randomly chosen end points (one on each side of the chasm), plus a small number or randomly chosen intermediate points in the chasm. You would end up with a physically 'realistic' bridge and a reasonably optimized cost of concrete.